# Exclude certain id's from query

Tags: php, sql

I got two different websites that use one CMS. But when I add a menu item it shows on both sites. What I want to do is give the menu item a parent category and only read the parent category id on the site I want.

How can I accomplish this for example with this query?

```
"SELECT * FROM `lb_categories` WHERE parent_id = '".$menu['id']."' order by rgt ASC"
```

I tried:

```
"SELECT * FROM `lb_categories` WHERE parent_id = '".$menu['id']."' and parent_id NOT IN ('30') order by rgt ASC"
```

Comment: You might want to show us the PHP code whence the `$menu` array is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, you can't string conditions on an attribute, you have to specify the column for each condition. So something like:

```
"SELECT * FROM `lb_categories` WHERE parent_id = '".$menu['id']."' and parent_id NOT IN ('30') order by rgt ASC"
```

Comment: Alright, I added the name of the field before the condition, but still it shows the menu item with id 30.

Comment: Could you show what the evaluated query looks like? In other words, the query which is actually fired to the database?

Comment: Can you explain more? This is the query that is fired into the database right? Only difference is that menu id is an actual id when fired into the database.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant, what's the value for the menu id? Although on second thought, I can't imagine how it would it would matter. Shouldn't it be `and '".$menu['id']."' NOT IN ('30')`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to put the name of the field before the NOT IN.

```
"SELECT * FROM `lb_categories` WHERE parent_id = '".$menu['id']."' and parent_id NOT IN ('30') order by rgt ASC"
```

Comment: Yeah you're right, I forgot, but with this code it still shows the menu item with id 30. Is this correct sql?